# place link inside dropdown list in Yii Framework

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, yii

I have the `dropdown` list like this

```
   <?php echo $form->dropdownList($customers,'customer_name', CHtml::listData(Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'),
 array(
   'ajax'=> array(
             'type'=>'GET',
             'url'=>
             'data'=>
           ),
             'empty'=>--Select One---')); ?>
```

another link for creating a `new customer` is like this

```
 <?php echo CHtml::link('Create Customers', "",array(
        'style'=>'cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;',
        'onclick'=>"{addCustomers(); $('#dialogCustomers').dialog('open');}"));?>
```

I want the `create customer link` should come inside `dropdown list`.So how to place `create customer link inside the dropdown list`,how to merge the both links and create them into a single one?.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: a good question, but have you searched? there are lots of similar questions

Comment: What about CMap::mergeArray()?

Comment: Here `CMAP::mergeArray()` can't work as it will merge all the arrays,and I want that the array should not merge.

Comment: @bool.dev is there any hint for this question?

Comment: i had voted johnatan's answer already, hasn't it helped? what are the current problems?

Comment: ya johnathan answar is right but when you will use array inside array it will merge that array.In this case there is an array inside ajax..so by merging array it will not work.I had tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh i'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but from what i got you need something like this:

```php
echo $form->dropDownList(
    $customers,
    'customer_name',
    CMap::mergeArray(
        CHtml::listData(
            Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'
        ),
        array(
            'create_customer_link'=>'Create new customer'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'empty'=>array('Select'=>'--Select One---'),
        'id'=>'Customers_name',
        'ajax'=> array(
            'type'=>'GET',
            'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){
                if($("#Customers_name").val() == "create_customer_link") {
                    addCustomers();
                    $("#dialogCustomers").dialog("open");
                    return false;
                }
            }',
            'url'=>...
            'data'=>...
        ),
        'options'=>array(
            'create_customer_link' => array('class'=>'my_custom_css_class'),
            // ... etc. You can add any html option here.
            // check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail for more info
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: @newuser I corrected the code, so it works well.. Swapped "customer_name" and $customers, and changed "select" to "onchange".

Comment: I want the both option should come in a dropdown list.When I will click on create one it will use this one ` array(
        'empty'=>array('Select'=>'--Select One---'),
        'onchange'=>'js:if($(this).val() == "create_customer_link") {addCustomers(); $("#dialogCustomers").dialog("open");return false;}'
    )`

Comment: I did test the code. $customers should contain an id of selected Customer. CHtml::listData(Customers::model().... will create list of customers to put into dropdown.

Comment: ok thats good `CHtml::listData(
            Customers::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'customer_name'` will list all the customers name,but how u will use `array( 'empty'=>array('Select'=>'--Select One---'), 'onchange'=>'js:if($(this).val() == "create_customer_link") {addCustomers(); $("#dialogCustomers").dialog("open");return false;}' )` in the dropdown menu.How this will be added in the dropdown menu?

Comment: 'empty'=>array('Select'=>'--Select One---') will be added as another option to dropdownlist. and 'onchange' will be added as separate JavaScript script into your HTML code. Something like $('body').on('change','#customer_name',function(){....

Comment: well thanks @Johnatan for your answer.But let me know how you will handle if the dropDownList will have more `htmlOptions` in an array?
Let me clear about this I have the `dropdown list` with some `htmlOptions` and to use `htmlOptions` I have used associative arrays.As you have used `CMap::mergeArray`,it will merge all the arrays.so at that point how this will work?

Comment: @newuser I've merged `id=>customer_name` pairs of selected models and custom line with `Create new customer` line, not `htmlOptions`. If you want to add more htmlOptions to dropdown, then put it before/after `empty` or `onchange` option. Again, `htmlOptions` do not get merged.

Comment: @newuser the `CMap::mergeArray` is not on `hTmlOptions` its on `$data` paramteter of [`dropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail).
@Johnatan there is some mistake in your code. the first and second arguments of `dropDownList` are interchanged

Comment: @Johnathan have you checked my question again? I have used array inside an array in the ajax part.There is the problem.So how to solve that? Array inside an array??

Comment: @newuser Finally i understand what you mean. I've changed the code so it works with the ajax you put for dropDownList. Notice, that i've added `"id"` option for dropDownList and also added `beforeSend` function so it checks if ajax actually should be sent. Hopefully that solves the issue.

Comment: @Johnatan that finally worked.But can you tell me how to add classes to the options of the dropdown .

Comment: @newuser If you want to add particular classes to options, you have to add `options` array to `htmlOptions`. I've edited the code, so you can see the example. Also check out the link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement. you want to add links on the options of the drop down list.
This is simple way to do this.

```
                    <?php 
                      echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name', null,
                        $arrPopularCities, 
                        array(
                            'prompt' => 'Popular City',
                            'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle',
                            'style' => 'border-right:2px solid #4bacc6;',
                        )); 
                ?>
```

add bellow jquery

```
    $('#city_name').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        window.location.assign('<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('city/view'); ?>' + '?id=' + $(this).val());
    }
});
```